# How to code an app in Huawei GT 2 Pro wear to always keep on the screen active?

Tags: wear-os, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I investigated and Although I read documentations of [Huawei Wear Engine](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/device-overview-0000001072998921), I couldn't find any things. I knows this I should change power or keep-on setting but I did not find anthing. Even I know implementing a service to will affect system configuration but there is no any document about it. Could you help me about implement always keep on screen huawei GT2 Pro.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping screen on could be achieved via brightness.setKeepScreenOn(OBJECT)
https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/lite-wearable-system-screen-brightness-0000001122145264

Sample code is as follows:

brightness.setKeepScreenOn({
keepScreenOn: true,
success: function () {
console.log('handling set keep screen on success.')
},
fail: function (data, code) {
console.log('handling set keep screen on fail, code:' + code + ', data: ' + data);
},
});

Answer (score 0):

As@[Zinna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357441/zinna) mentioned, You can call `brightness.setKeepScreenOn(OBJECT)` to always keep on the screen active.

Examples are as follows:

```
brightness.setKeepScreenOn({
  keepScreenOn: true,
  success: function () {
    console.log('handling set keep screen on success.')
  },
  fail: function (data, code) {
    console.log('handling set keep screen on fail, code:' + code + ', data: ' + data);
  },
});
```

You are advised to invoke it in the `onShow()` phase to always keep the screen on.

For details, kindly refer to this [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/lite-wearable-system-screen-brightness-0000001122145264#section38761758481).